# Spark CREATE TABLE 'data_source' format vs 'Hive format'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table.html), there are 2 ways to CREATE TABLE

1. DATA_SOURCE format
2. Hive format

Syntactically, there doesn't seem to be much difference between them other than the storage clauses. i.e. '**USING <>**' (for datasource) vs '**STORED AS <>**' (for hive format).

Internally, what are the differences between the two? What are the situations when someone should prefer one over the other?

Thanks!